# ZXing The type or namespace name 'BitmapRenderer' could not be found

Tags: c#, barcode, zxing, zxing.net

I just updated ZXing.Net from version 0.16.6 to 0.16.9, and currently, I am encountering the following two errors:

- Using the generic type 'BarcodeWriter<TOutput>' requires 1 type arguments
- The type or namespace name 'BitmapRenderer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using ZXing;
using ZXing.QrCode.Internal;
using ZXing.Rendering;

namespace BarCode.Commons
{
    public class BarCodeUtil
    {
        public static Bitmap GenerateBar(string text, int margin = 0, int width = 1000, int height = 500)
        {
            var bw = new BarcodeWriter(); // The first error is here
            var encOptions = new ZXing.Common.EncodingOptions
            {
                Width = width + ( 2 * margin),
                Height = height + ( 2 * margin),
                Margin = margin,
                PureBarcode = true
            };
            encOptions.Hints.Add(EncodeHintType.ERROR_CORRECTION, ErrorCorrectionLevel.H);
            bw.Renderer = new BitmapRenderer(); // The second error is here
            bw.Options = encOptions;
            bw.Format = BarcodeFormat.CODE_128;
            Bitmap bm = bw.Write(text);
            return bm;
        }
    }
}
```

For the first error, it seems that I need to specify one output type, and I have modified it to the following command:

```
var bw = new BarcodeWriter<Bitmap>();
```

However, I don't know how to resolve the second error.

Comment: regardless of the core problem of your question, another small hint: you should better use 'ZXing.OneD.Code128EncodingOptions' class instead of 'ZXing.Common.EncodingOptions'. The Code128EncodingOptions class has a property for all hints that are available for Code128. The line 'encOptions.Hints.Add(EncodeHintType.ERROR_CORRECTION, ErrorCorrectionLevel.H);' doesn't have any effect at the generation of Code128.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are using .Net Core or .Net 5.0 or above.
In that case, the base nuget package ZXing.Net doesn't include a BarcodeWriter implementation for a specific bitmap implementation.
Only the old classic .Net framework 4.x includes the Bitmap classes by default.

If my assumption is correct, you have to select one of the binding packages: https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Zxing.Net.Binding
Perhaps this specific one should fit your needs:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/ZXing.Net.Bindings.Windows.Compatibility
(ZXing.Windows.Compatibility.BarcodeWriter)
Change your code to

```
var bw = new ZXing.Windows.Compatibility.BarcodeWriter();
```

or add the following "using" statement at the top of your file

```
using ZXing.Windows.Compatibility;
```